# Passing back Array from Java to ESQL in IIB

Tags: java, integration, extended-sql

I am looking to pass back the list of 'Userdefined' configuration list from Java to ESQL in IIB. I can pass back the single value but looking for the complete list. Below is the Java and ESQL code. Any inputs are much appreciated.

ESQL code:

```
CREATE COMPUTE MODULE SiteCodeValdationRoutine_Compute
CREATE FUNCTION Main() RETURNS BOOLEAN
BEGIN
    CALL CopyEntireMessage();           
    CALL getSiteCodeProperties(Environment.MFT.Sitecode);   
    RETURN TRUE;
END;

CREATE PROCEDURE CopyEntireMessage() BEGIN
    SET OutputRoot = InputRoot;
END;

CREATE PROCEDURE getSiteCodeProperties( OUT Sitecode CHARACTER)
    LANGUAGE JAVA EXTERNAL NAME "com.nb.iib.util.SiteCodeParameterLookup.getSiteCodeParameters";
END MODULE;
```

Java Code:

```
package com.nb.iib.util;

import java.util.Properties;
import com.ibm.broker.config.proxy.BrokerProxy;
import com.ibm.broker.config.proxy.ConfigurableService;

public class SiteCodeParameterLookup {

    public static void getSiteCodeParameters(String siteCodeArray[]) {

        siteCodeArray = new String[10];
        BrokerProxy bp = null;
        try {
            // Grab Local Broker Proxy
            bp = BrokerProxy.getLocalInstance();
            if (bp == null) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Could not obtain Broker Proxy Connection");
            }
            // Search up
            ConfigurableService[] ud_set = bp.getConfigurableServices("UserDefined");
            if (ud_set == null) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Could not find Site Code value under User Defined Properties: ");
            }

            // Add
            System.out.println("Configurable Service Name :" + ud_set[0].getName());

            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                siteCodeArray[i] = ud_set[i].getName();
            }
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "SiteCodeNotConfigured. Sitecode configuration missing in User Definied Properties", t);
        } finally {
            // Disconnect Broker Proxy when use is complete
            if (bp != null)
                bp.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

I need to pass back the `siteCodeArray` to ESQL.

Answer (score 0):

So ESQL doesn't do arrays but you can create a set of nodes in the Environment tree. Get a pointer to the Environment tree and create a subtree containing a set of nodes one for each entry in the array.

Embed something like this into your code.

```
MbMessage env = assembly.getGlobalEnvironment();
MbElement siteCodes = env.getRootElement().createElementAsLastChild(MbElement.TYPE_NAME, "SiteCodes", null);
for(ConfigurableService cs: ud_set) {
    siteCodes.createElementAsLastChild(MbElement.TYPE_NAME_VALUE, "SiteCode", cs.getName());
}
```